# SQLite database manipulation

Tags: android, sqlite

In MS SQL we have the studio manager and in mySql we have php myAdmin to manage the database.
So we can write queries and check the data is ok and manipulate the database with out the implemented software.

Isn't there any way that we can handle SQLite database in this way. It is really hard to confirm the data we inserted have successfully inserted or what. Have to code each time

I found a software called sqlite database browser but don't know how to open the required database.

File -> open database -> ?????

I know the DB file is in, /data/data/package_name/databases

but how to find it in windows explorer.

Thank you

Comment: There are addons available for ur browser, using tat u can access the database. Addon name SQLite Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Just pick one: http://sqlite.com/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools

Comment: File -> open database -> ?????

I know the DB file is in, /data/data/package_name/databases

but how to find it in windows explorer.

Comment: Have a look at achie's answer. It's not possible with Windows Explorer out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

use adb pull command to copy the database to your local machine and do whatever you want on that database copy.

[More details here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#copyfiles)

Also check [Examining sqlite3 Databases from a Remote Shell](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite)